# CSS image appearing on navigation bar on hover acting weird?

Tags: html, css

So down below you see an image of the problem im currently experiencing. I have some classes in lists and on hover i make it so their background image change to a specific image. Basically its acting really weird when it fades in, in a way it kinda jumps into the box instead of fading in which is the problem. I want the image to fade in, not jump in like on the image you can see down below. Anyways, here is my code, thanks in advance for help:

```css
#NavBar ul {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
#NavBar li {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#NavBar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#NavBar .hjem:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
#NavBar .olie:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/olie_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
#NavBar .kul:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/kul_navbar.png");
  background-size: 45px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
#NavBar .naturgas:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/naturgas_navbar.png");
  background-size: 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="hjem" href="index.html">Hjem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="olie" href="olie.html">Olie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="kul" href="kul.html">Kul</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="naturgas" href="naturgas.html">Naturgas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: This is basically the problem]

Comment: It looks pretty cool like this

Comment: I think it's because you have `transition` set to 'all'. Try changing it to `transition: background-color .5s` to limit the transition to only the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have to specify their `width` before doing the `:hover` effect.

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/2k3kpcce/1/)

```
#NavBar .olie, #NavBar .hjem, #NavBar .naturgas, #NavBar .kul { 
  background-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem, cant believe it was so simple =)

Answer (score 1):

Add the property which needs to be transitioned, like `transition: background ease-in .5s;`

```css
#NavBar ul {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
#NavBar li {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#NavBar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: background ease-in .5s;
  -ms-transition: background ease-in .5s;
  -moz-transition: background ease-in .5s;
  -webkit-transition: background ease-in .5s;
  transition: background ease-in .5s;
}
#NavBar .hjem:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
#NavBar .olie:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/olie_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
#NavBar .kul:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/kul_navbar.png");
  background-size: 45px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
#NavBar .naturgas:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/naturgas_navbar.png");
  background-size: 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="hjem" href="index.html">Hjem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="olie" href="olie.html">Olie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="kul" href="kul.html">Kul</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="naturgas" href="naturgas.html">Naturgas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```